# Parallel HTTP requests in batches with async for loop for each request

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to run parallel requests in batches to an API using a bunch of keywords in an array. [Article by Denis Fatkhudinov](https://itnext.io/node-js-handling-asynchronous-operations-in-parallel-69679dfae3fc).

The problem I am having is that for each keyword, I need to run the request again with a different `page` argument for as many times as the number in the `pages` variable.

I keep getting `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` for the return of the `chainNext` function.

The parallel request in batches on its own, without the for loop, works great, I am struggling to incorporate the for loop on the process.

```
// Parallel requests in batches
async function runBatches() {
  // The keywords to request with 
  const keywords = ['many keyword strings here...'];
  // Set max concurrent requests
  const concurrent = 5;
  // Clone keywords array
  const keywordsClone = keywords.slice()
  // Array for future resolved promises for each batch
  const promises = new Array(concurrent).fill(Promise.resolve());
  // Async for loop
  const asyncForEach = async (pages, callback) => {
    for (let page = 1; page <= pages; page++) {
      await callback(page);
    }
  };
  // Number of pages to loop for
  const pages = 2;

  // Recursively run batches
  const chainNext = (pro) => {
    // Runs itself as long as there are entries left on the array
    if (keywordsClone.length) {
      // Store the first entry and conviently also remove it from the array
      const keyword = keywordsClone.shift();
      // Run 'the promise to be' request
      return pro.then(async () => {
        // ---> Here was my problem, I am declaring the constant before running the for loop
        const promiseOperation = await asyncForEach(pages, async (page) => {
          await request(keyword, page)
        });
        // ---> The recursive invocation should also be inside the for loop
        return chainNext(promiseOperation);
      });
    }

    return pro;
  }

  return await Promise.all(promises.map(chainNext));
}

// HTTP request
async function request(keyword, page) { 
  try {
    // request API 
    const res = await apiservice(keyword, page);
    // Send data to an outer async function to process the data
    await append(res.data);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error) 
  }
}


runBatches()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by moving actual request `promiseOperation` inside the for loop and returning the recursive function there too

```
// Recursively run batches
const chainNext = async (pro) => {
  if (keywordsClone.length) {
    const keyword = keywordsClone.shift()
    return pro.then(async () => {
      await asyncForEach(pages, (page) => {
        const promiseOperation = request(keyword, page)
        return chainNext(promiseOperation)
      })
    })
  }
  return pro
}
```

Credit for the parallel requests in batches goes to https://itnext.io/node-js-handling-asynchronous-operations-in-parallel-69679dfae3fc

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that pro is undefined, because you haven't initialized it.

You basically execute this code:

```
Promise.all(new Array(concurrent).fill(Promise.resolve().map(pro => {
  // pro is undefined here because the Promise.resolve had no parameter
  return pro.then(async () => {})
}));
```

I'm not completely sure about your idea behind that, but this is your problem in a more condensed version.

Comment: It's meant to be undefined at the beginning, I took the batched code from https://itnext.io/node-js-handling-asynchronous-operations-in-parallel-69679dfae3fc and there it also says undefined but then they get filled and all works fine